# Passing an object from controller to a modal view rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to pass an object fro my controller to my modal view.

in my index.html.erb

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="email-template-user-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <%= render "shared/email_template_user", :locals => { :application => @applicant }%>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

     <%= link_to application.loan_application.email, lp_banker_assignments_get_email_status_path(:applicant_id => application.loan_application.id), class: 'email-template-user-modal', id: "email-template-user-id", :data => { :toggle => "modal", :target => "#email-template-user-modal"} %>
```

in my controller.rb

```
def get_email_status
    @applicant = LoanApplication.where(:id => params[:applicant_id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json
    end   
  end
```

in my modal view file _email_template_user.html.erb

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">Compose Email</h4>
    **<%= ap @applicant %>**
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <%= form_tag :action => 'email_status', class: 'form-horizontal' do %> 
        <div class="">
          <div class="col-md-3">Recipient</div>
          <div class="col-md-9">
            <%= email_field_tag "recipient", "", class: " string optional form-control"%>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
```

If i call @applicant in my modal file, it returns nil besides in my cmd log i realise that i get an error about `Missing Template lp_banker_assignments/get_email_status, application/get_email_status with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee, :slim]}. Searched in:`

How do i get my object to show in my modal view?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can create `get_email_status.js.erb` file in your corresponding view folder as your controller action is expecting json in respond block. Hope it works.

Comment: if i create d file in d folder, then what do i put in d file?

Comment: You could write both js or erb contents so as to modify your views. Moreover, you can pass your variable via controller with this contents in your respond block.       format.js { render json: @your_variable }

Comment: i tried ur option @sansarp nd it renders only d object on d page nd not nthg else on d partial file.